# One Controller for multiple apps

Tags: cakephp

I have written a tool with cakePHP that will make government departments management of entities much easier.

What I want to know is, is it possible to have many apps running off this one system? What I am asking is, if we have 5 different departments, we will have 5 different apps. Will it be possible for me to, if I make changes to one Controller, I can upload it so that it affects all 5 apps at once? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Yes that is possible and described in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#sharing-cakephp-libraries-with-multiple-applications)

Comment: If I look at the docs, it still seems to me that for each variation of the app, you'll need an app directory that has its own Controllers, Models and Views. I want to know if it's possible to set it up in such a way that you can just update the controller/model/view once and it changes on all the apps.

Comment: That is also possible and described in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in)

Comment: Use a plugin if you want to share functionality.

Comment: Question is to broad to answer...please mention at least one example

Comment: @noslone - I don't believe either of your links help him out or explain anything about what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Make this submodule of the app for managing the departments entities a plugin.

Then use composer or gits submodule feature to update the different apps. The advantage here is you can set each app  to a specific commit id. If you blindly update all apps at once it is likely that one of them might break. I would not do that.

If you really want to do it you can simply check the plugin out somewhere on the server and symlink it to all your apps.